# When to store Firebase chat message into SQLite

Tags: android, firebase

I know many chat app(one to one) using SQLite locally to store messages
and I also think to store every message in Firestore databases
is not good.

but here I confused
When two users are online and seeing chat at the same time
it is not a problem
but one sent message and another one came after it would be a problem
I mean how to store them into SQLite? 
another one does not have a message to store because when he came back
it`s nothing

thank you for advice

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). Please note that Firestire has offline persistence enabled by default. There is no need for an additional database.

Answer (score 0):

Well I  don't see any problem saving all messages on database if you want offline integration, just code a way to delete all your messages whenever the user wants. If you're afraid of size growth of your app, I suggest you to make your own test, take a clean install and save 100 messages on your database and see how much bytes the data storage increasead.
You should care more about loading your messages, you'll need to develop pagination aproach to load your data and you'll be fine